# Error while building a cpp application by linking with PCL

Tags: c++, build, cmake, point-cloud-library

I built PCL on windows using VCPKG(MS Visual studio 2017). I am trying to build a CPP application with PCL using cmake 3.12 with the following CMakelists.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(compute)

find_package(PCL 1.5 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (compute compute.cpp)
target_link_libraries (compute ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

I also set the following environment variables.

```
set PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS="C:\vcpkg-pcl\vcpkg-master\installed\x64-windows\include\pcl"
SET PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS="C:\vcpkg-pcl\vcpkg-master\installed\x64-windows\lib"
set PCL_LIBRARIES="pcl_common_release.lib;pcl_features_release.lib;pcl_filters_release.lib;pcl_io_ply_release.lib;pcl_io_release.lib"
```

I initially got an error saying it is unable to find the file FindPCL.cmake and eventually PCLConfig.cmake or PCL-Config.cmake. I set the environment variable

`set PCL_DIR=C:\vcpkg-pcl\vcpkg-master\installed\x64-windows\share\pcl`

where the PCLConfig.cmake is installed. It was able to detect the file. However,
it is unable to detect PCL(pcl_report_not_found) with the following error.

```
c:\PCL-Program>cmake .
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.17134.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27023.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27023.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Could NOT find Eigen (missing: EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at C:/vcpkg-pcl/vcpkg-master/installed/x64-windows/share/pcl/PCLConfig.cmake:56 (message):
  common is required but eigen was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/vcpkg-pcl/vcpkg-master/installed/x64-windows/share/pcl/PCLConfig.cmake:356 (pcl_report_not_found)
  C:/vcpkg-pcl/vcpkg-master/installed/x64-windows/share/pcl/PCLConfig.cmake:526 (find_external_library)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/PCL-Program/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

c:\PCL-Program>set EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR
EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\vcpkg-pcl\vcpkg-master\installed\x64-windows\include\Eigen
```

Even after setting the environment variable for EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR, I am still getting the same error. Please let me know if I am following the right way.

Thanks!

Comment: Variable `EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR` is an output variable. For hint, set `EIGEN_ROOT` variable instead. That variable should be set to directory, which contains `Eigen/Core` file inside. Probably, it is `C:\vcpkg-pcl\vcpkg-master\installed\x64-windows\include` directory in your system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After adding EIGEN_ROOT variable it was able to go ahead. But I am getting another error. -- Looking for pthread.h - not found. even after I installed Pthreads using VCPKG. and set the environment variable PTHREADS_ROOT or PTHREADS_INCLUDE to C:\vcpkg-pcl\vcpkg-master\installed\x64-windows or C:\vcpkg-pcl\vcpkg-master\installed\x64-windows\include. Any help on this is appreciated